# How can I solve my dependency problems with a resolvconf/dnsmasq installation script?

Tags: dependencies, puppet

I have the following Puppet module:

```
class resolvconf {
    $packages = ['resolvconf', 'dnsmasq']
    package { $packages: ensure => installed, }

    file { '/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base':
        ensure  => file,
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
        content => '
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4',
    }

    service { 'dnsmasq':
        require   => Package[resolvconf],
        ensure    => running,
        subscribe => File['/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base']
    }
}
```

However, when I run the provisioning, I get the following error:

> err: /Stage[main]/Resolvconf/File[/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file on ensure: No such file or directory - /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base.puppettmp_4012 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/resolvconf/manifests/init.pp:13

I understand this to mean that */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base* does not exist yet, or can't be created. This problem seems to eventually go away after a number of re-provisionings or a reboot, so it would seem to be some sort of a dependency problem that I could resolve with the appropriate dependency or exec statement.

In addition, because of this failed dependency, the following will hang indefinitely:

```
notice: /Stage[main]/Resolvconf/Service[dnsmasq]: Dependency File[/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base] has failures: true
warning: /Stage[main]/Resolvconf/Service[dnsmasq]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

or at least until I hit <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>.

What do I need to change in the module or manifest to allow the script to run correctly the first time through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to require the package in your file resource like this:

```
file { '/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base':
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    content => '...
    require => Package['resolvconf'],
}
```

Using a require basically forced puppet to perform the package install first.

This of course assumes that the installation of the resolvconf package creates the required directories, which I believe it does happen.